# Exponents in big-O notation

Tags: math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity

Is 3<sup>n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>)? how about (3/2)<sup>n</sup> = O(2<sup>n</sup>)? Can you explain the answers?

I got false for the first since, 3<sup>n</sup> grows faster then 2<sup>n</sup> no matter what constant C you multiply 2<sup>n</sup> by. And same for the second?

How about log(3<sup>n</sup>) = O(log (2<sup>n</sup>) )? I think we can't determine this because we don't know the base of the log.

Comment: The base of the log changes the numbers by a constant factor, so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's actually prove a stronger result: for any constants r<sub>0</sub> and r<sub>1</sub> where 1 ≤ r<sub>0</sub> < r<sub>1</sub>, it is true that r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> = O(r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>) and it is false that r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> = r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup>.  This proves your result as a special case, since 1 < 3/2 < 2.

To prove the first part, we'll show that r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> = O(r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>).  To do this, we'll use the definition of big-O and find values of n<sub>0</sub> and c such that for any n > n<sub>0</sub>, we have that

> r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> ≤ c r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>

We can choose n = n<sub>0</sub> and can choose c = 1.  The above inequality then holds, so by definition we have that r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup> = O(r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup>).

To prove the second part, we'll show that r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> ≠ O(r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup>).  To do this, we'll proceed by contradiction.  Assume for the sake of contradiction that there exists a choice of c and n<sub>0</sub> such that for any n > n<sub>0</sub>, we have that

> r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> ≤ c r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup>

Take the log of both sides to get

> n log r<sub>1</sub> ≤ log (c r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup>)
>
> n log r<sub>1</sub> ≤ log c + n log r<sub>0</sub>
>
> n (log r<sub>1</sub> - log r<sub>0</sub>) ≤ log c
>
> n log(r<sub>1</sub> / r<sub>0</sub>) ≤ log c
>
> n ≤ log c / (log(r<sub>1</sub> / r<sub>0</sub>))

But now we're in trouble, since this statement should hold for any choice of n.  However, if we pick any choice of n greater than log c / (log(r<sub>1</sub> / r<sub>0</sub>)), the statement becomes false.

We have reached a contradiction, so our assumption must have been wrong.  Thus if 1 < r<sub>0</sub> < r<sub>1</sub>, we have that r<sub>1</sub><sup>n</sup> ≠ O(r<sub>0</sub><sup>n</sup>).

Hope this helps!